# Eliminate skewing effect in combined track and zoom

Tags: graphics, image-rendering

*I am writing for HTML5 Canvas, using it as a viewport on which I maintain a central origin and zoom level. I want to track and zoom to a region, but have encountered a naturally occurring effect that spoils the look I am trying to obtain. This question concerns how I might mitigate this while preserving a natural-looking effect.*

Imagine I have a downwards-pointing camera mounted on the ceiling, and somewhere on the floor is a piece of paper. I move the camera at a constant speed along the ceiling until it is above the paper, while zooming at a linear rate so that the paper will eventually fill the rendered image. These actions occur simultaneously.

When doing this, an effect can be observed whereby the paper slides out of frame before it returns to centre. This is probably best explained visually, and kept to two dimensions:

[image: img]

This is not a good look. Consider the user requesting focus on something. Their conceptualization is that the entity is moving into view, and it is strange, then, that it appears to first move away before it comes closer.

**The effect I wish for is of the target object only approaching the centre of the frame, and never retreating.** I suppose the answer is to deform the rate of zoom somehow (or the rate of movement, though I would not prefer this) presumably as a function of the distances involved, or artificially adjust the zoom so the page is kept in frame. I would prefer help towards a solution along the lines of the former approach.

Comment: The GIF is the FOV of the camera and red is the paper? (uppre line is ceiling lower is ground...) do you have a skewed images? may be you should just pan first and mitigate the skew from that .... only after that add zooming and correct that.... as trying to counteract both at once might be difficult at first.... To avoid the initial problem/effect (its not a skew btw) you can zoom nonlinearly .... or compute the zoom so the right side of the FOV stays on the paper edge

Comment: what exactly and how you can affect/control the pan or zoom or both?

Comment: @Spektre The gif is as you describe it, and I have added to the top of the post in answer to your second comment. The operations being simultaneous is a requirement. I used the word "skew" as in "a deviation from the straight line" (OED), being the straight line I want the paper to appear to travel in on the rendered output, but if you have a better word then I thank you and will be happy to update. (On a similar note, the camera is "tracking", not "panning".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ow so you got an SW implementation no HW camera involved ....

I was referring to the **real skew effect** in English called [Rolling shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter): if you are obtaining image by moving real HW scanline camera (without [**TDI** technology](https://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/product/cameras/tdi-cameras/principle/index.html)) then a skew+blur effect is appearing sliding the scan lines ... try to make a photo from a side window of a moving car the image will get skewed.

The **effect you are describing** has nothing to do with skew its just a mathematical "singularity" sorry I do not have any name therm for it.

As your camera is **SW** only you can affect both pan and zoom to your liking so I would just compute the `zoom` from camera **FOV** and `pan` position. I see it like this:

[image: overview]

So:

```
 I. a = FOV / zoom
II. tan(0.5*a) = (x1-x0) / h
------------------------
zoom = 0.5*FOV/atan( (x1-x0) / h )
```

Where `h` is the ceiling height, `x0` is the camera (pan) position, `x0` is paper edge position and `FOV` is field of view of your non zoomed camera...

**[edit1] sliding the paper in and animation...**

I ended up with this:

[image: animation]

Here the **C++/VCL** code for this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double x0,x1,w=50,h=200,FOVx=60.0*M_PI/180.0,zoom,pan;
double t=0; // animation parameter <0,1>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    if (!_redraw) return;

    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    double y0,y1,dx;

    // position side view onto screen based on its size xs,ys
    y0=0.5*(ys-h);
    y1=y0+h;
    x0=0.5*xs;
    x1=x0+(h*tan(0.5*FOVx));
    // compute zoom,pan from t
    pan=(x1-x0+(0.5*w))*t;
    zoom=0.5*FOVx/atan(((1.0-t)*(x1-x0)+(0.5*w*t))/h);
    // scene
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlue;
    bmp->Canvas->MoveTo( 0,y0);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(xs,y0);
    bmp->Canvas->MoveTo( 0,y1);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(xs,y1);
    // paper
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clRed;
    bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x1+w,y1);
    // FOVx
    dx=h*tan(0.5*FOVx/zoom);
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clAqua;
    bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x0+pan-dx,y1);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x0+pan,y0);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x0+pan+dx,y1);
    // points
    dx=4;
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clAqua;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlue;
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x0-dx,y0-dx,x0+dx,y0+dx);
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x0+pan-dx,y0-dx,x0+pan+dx,y0+dx);
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x1-dx,y1-dx,x1+dx,y1+dx);
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Color=clYellow;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
    bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(x0,y0-20,"x0");
    bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(x0+pan+20,y0+5,"x0+pan");
    bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(x1,y1+5,"x1");
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;

    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    _redraw=false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you ignore the rendering stuff this is what is important for you:

```
pan=(x1-x0+(0.5*w))*t;
zoom=0.5*FOVx/atan(((1.0-t)*(x1-x0)+(0.5*w*t))/h);
```

So I slightly changed the meaning of `x1` (its the other edge of paper) and instead of `x1` in the original equations above I used `x1+w*t` which means that the paper is not in view at start (`t=0`) but its touching it from outside and it is fully in view when `(t=1)`. The rest is just the result of the substitution ...

The `w` is the paper width, `t=<0.0,1.0>` is the animation parameter and all the other values did not change meaning...

The animation is just incrementing the `t` by `0.02` in 150ms timer recorded by my GIF encoder (that is why its so choppy)

Comment: This is a great explanation of the second approach I identified at the end of my original post. I am not going to accept it (yet) as I am holding out for an example of the first.

Comment: @NikGibbs I added [edit1] with an example (by first example did you mean that?) also I had a bug in the equation (the FOVx should be haved I repaired it)